# Using a self join and a join with a third table in one query

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I would like to self join on a table and then join this to a third table...below is my attempt but I get a 904 error on line 4 "a.employee_t.employeeid". Is this possible and what syntax would I use?

```
SELECT a.employeename, b.employeename
FROM employee_t a, employee_t b
JOIN employeeskills_t ON 
a.employee_t.employeeid=employeeskills_t.employeeid;
```

EDIT: I should have hesitated before posting this because my code was
 very nonsensical...I'll post below with proper syntax (no 904 errors)

```
SELECT a.employeename, b.employeename, employeeskills_t.skillid
FROM employee_t a
JOIN employee_t b ON a.employeeid=b.employeeid
JOIN employeeskills_t ON a.employeeid=employeeskills_t.employeeid;
```

I'm using Oracle Database version 12.2.0.1.0

Comment: How are you self-joining `employee_t`? E.g. is there a `supervisor_id` attribute you're joining (`a.employee_id = b.supervisor_id`)?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Downvote because you didn't specify which DBMS you're using. Will gladly retract if you'll edit that in.

Comment: Oracle sql developer, it's in the post now

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is the *client*, not the DBMS (Database Management System, the server side part). You're most likely using Oracle's database. Which version?

Comment: the database is 12.2.0.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of guesswork here.. maybe this is what you are looking for? I assume you want to expand this query it is not making much sence right now.

```
SELECT a.employeename, b.employeename
FROM employee_t a
JOIN employee_t b on a.employeeid= b.employeeid
JOIN employeeskills_t c ON a.employeeid=c.employeeid;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not use different syntaxis. employee_t a, employee_t b must be joined via JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be something like this:

```
SELECT a.employeename, b.employeename
FROM employee_t a
JOIN employee_t b ON
b.employeeid = a.employeeid (YOUR JOIN CONDITION)
JOIN employeeskills_t ON
employeeskills_t.employeeid = a.employeeid;
```

Note that I changed the Join condition `a.employee_t.employeeid=employeeskills_t.employeeid` because you used the table alias as well as the table name.